# How can I set a scalable background to the 'LauncherScreen.Storyboard' of ios in xamarin.forms

Tags: ios, xamarin, mobile, layout, storyboard

Can someone help me about a thing?
How can I set a scalable background to the 'LauncherScreen.Storyboard' of ios in xamarin.forms?
I tried it setting height and width to any x any, and putting a image filling out the screen..Content mode = scale to fill...But When I run the app the image is cutted...I Believe the problem is the constraint because I really don't now ho to use they...they look like to be used to set the distance of views and not to set a background as a scallable background to a page...
Am I right?
How can I set a scalable background ?

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: so so, because it worked (the constraints) when I am working with Iphones, but, when I debug with an Ipad, the launch screen doesn't scale...